# Closing the child no errors but sub movie wont close

Tags: actionscript, external

Hi i have looked up a lot of answers but havnt been able to fix my problem. I am using external actionscript and i have used the following code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;

    public class submenu1 extends MovieClip
    {
        private var movieLoader:Loader; 

        //everything in this function is exicuted when you start the application
        public function submenu1()
        {
            movieLoader = new Loader(); 

            image3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,addMovie);
            image4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,addMovie);
            exit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,closeTheMovie);

        }


        private function addMovie(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            if(e.target.name=="image3_btn")
            {
                loadTheMovie("image3");
            }
            else if(e.target.name=="image4_btn")
            {
                loadTheMovie("image4");
            }

        }
        private function loadTheMovie(m:String)
        {
            var movieRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../swf/" + m + ".swf");
            movieLoader.load(movieRequest);
            addChild(movieLoader);
        }

        private function closeTheMovie (e:MouseEvent)
{
        removeChild(movieLoader);
        exit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,closeTheMovie);
        }
        }

        }
```

I can get the sub movie to open but i cant get the exit_btn to close the sub movie and return to the original. I am wanting the exit_btn when clicked to remove the child and take you back to the texture page. The flash itself doesn't bring up any errors just the button wont work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you export to actions script your exit buttons? Right click on the exit button then choose properties and then click on the box called export for actionScript.